# How can I get gnu watch to run in the background?

Tags: command-line, watch

If I start a `watch` command in the background, it stops. Bringing the job to the foreground makes it run again, but I want this to run in the background.

```
$ watch ./do-something.sh &
[1] 97673
[1]+  Stopped                 watch ./do-something.sh
```

I expect this job to be running in the background, but it isnt

```
$ bg 1
[1]+ watch ./hello.sh &
[1]+  Stopped                 watch ./hello.sh
```

That doesn't do anything either. Starting the job in the foreground and moving in the background with Ctrl-Z and "starting" it with `bg 1` doesn't work either.

Is this a "feature" of watch? I just want to periodically run something, every few seconds, and I don't particularly care about the output. (cron is not the right tool for this, fwiw).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I just want to periodically run something, every few seconds, and I don't particularly care about the output. (cron is not the right tool for this, fwiw).

And neither is `watch`. It's designed for *interactively* monitoring the output of some command – it will refuse to run in background if it cannot control the terminal, like any other interactive program.

Try something simpler:

```
while sleep 2; do ./do-something.sh; done &
```

---

Oh, and cron *would* be the right tool to do this – that's its only job, after all. There's only the limitation of not being able to specify jobs with second precision.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; that's a good answer. I also piped stdout and stderr to /dev/null since I wasn't interested in the output.